# рефакторинг импорта

Tags: python, pycharm, рефакторинг

Есть куча файлов Python с from imports (например, `from time import sleep`). Как автоматически изменить весь этот импорт на простые (например, `import time`) и все вхождения объектов на префиксные (например, вместо `sleep()` `time.sleep()`)?